# Is there a Rubik's scramble generator for the top layer only?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I want to practice solving the last layer, but the online scramblers I've seen are full cube only.

**Is there a Rubik's scramble generator for the top layer only?**

Comment: Why the downvotes? I don't see any issues with this question.

Comment: I agree, it seems fine,  unless requests for resources are off-topic/should be in meta...? Not sure since I'm new here.

Comment: @Silenus: Nope, questions about puzzles are perfectly fine here, and this is definitely a question about puzzles. Meta is for discussion of the site itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [ChaoTimer](http://www.chaotimer.com/) on the App Store. You can swipe up with two fingers to choose a different scramble.

Comment: I upvoted this answer but I do actually have two objections,

  - To the answer itself because the link is out of date
  - To ChaoTimer because no matter how great it might be, it's for iOS only